# SSL error while running asp.net error 107

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl

I am trying to run an HTTPS project from my laptop. Before using the HTTPS, I was using the HTTP, at that time I was stuck with an error of

> You don't have access to view this page. You need to sign in.

Now when I am using the HTTPS it says me

> SQL connection error - Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL
>   protocol error

I have changed the bindings and the SSL settings from the IIS, but it still gives me same error. Please help guys, if you can find the solution. I am so confused here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you checked your ssl certificates.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286707/apache-ssl-configuration-error-ssl-connection-error

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have checked the SSL certificates. But still it gives me the same error. When I try loading it from Visual Studio (Start new instance), it doesn't give any response and end-up with loading time error (too much time). What should I do?