# Liferay-cas integration

Tags: ssl, liferay, liferay-6, cas

I'm trying to integrate liferay 6.1 and cas server.
liferay and cas are running on same machine's different ports.
I can't access cas server via https. I tried to generate ssl cert like this 
https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CAS+Liferay+6+Integration
but still not working. I created certificate for localhost, servername and ip address. All not worked.
When clicked sign in button on liferay it redirects to cas page. After try to login on cas page, i am getting  "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".
Can anyone help me to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the JRE that you are using to start Liferay trusts the autogen certificate that uses CAS for HTTPS? That is, keytool -import -alias tomcat -file %FILE_NAME% -keypass changeit -keystore %JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to verify the configs, This link describes about the similar problem.

[Apache SSL Configuration Error (SSL Connection Error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286707/apache-ssl-configuration-error-ssl-connection-error)